# How to tokenize line, without a list into it?

Tags: tcl

How to tokenize line, without a list into it. For example for such lines:

```
name name1 name2 name3 3.41 787.0 5.0 8.0
```

this regexp works great:

```
set lst [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
```

But for such lines:

```
name1 name2 { name1 name2 name3 }
```

I would like to get list of the 3 items: `name1  name2 { name1 name2 name3 }`

Comment: You already have it. Just use it as list. Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is a well-formed Tcl list already. However, if that isn't guaranteed, you can use a regular expression to do the extraction:

```
set lst [lrange [regexp -inline {^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\{(.*)\}\s*$} $line] 1 end]
```

This will work fine even when you have unbalanced braces and other such nasties.

Another alternative is to use `scan`:

```
set lst [scan $line "%s %s {%\[^{}]}"]
```

Be aware that if you are using `scan`, only `%[…]` (which needs a backslash in double-quoted strings, as above) will read spaces as part of a scanned specifier. I usually prefer to write regular expressions, but you don't have to…